# What does this artwork say? (Characters identified: 湖岩)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

I'd like to ask you for help me to identify this sign and stample. It should be painting on silk.

[image]

Comment: It seems like "湖岩"   +1 ~~

Answer (score 1):

In Chinese, 湖岩 means seaside cliff.  湖岩 also seems to be the name of a Nobel-esque award for ethnic Koreans: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho-Am_Prize